# Is there a way to use .splitlines() and .split() at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

```
Ex.
'xxx-xxx, xxx-xxx'.splitlines.split()
```

I know this might not be the correct to write it but I'm trying to show what I am trying to do. Is there a way to split the list into separate ", " and then separate the "-" at the same time. I want each 'xxx' to be to be like this.

```
[[xxx, xxx], [xxx, xxx]]
```

Maybe this is the hard way and there is a better way to organize these list. I need to organize them something like this.

Comment: Don't you really want to split on the comma? `splitlines` splits on newlines, which you don't have.

Comment: Yes, I need to separate each comma sections so I add the data in groups to a function. I'm new to all this still. Just experimenting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
[line.strip().split('-') for line in text.split(',')]
```

You are not splitting lines (there are no line separators), you are splitting on commas.